# Remove duplicates only when they occur in pair per group

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following data:

| id_1 | id_2 | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-02 | scroll fast | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-02 | scroll fast | 12 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | scroll fast fast | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | scroll fast fast | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | scroll fast fast | 11 |

I would like to remove duplicates only when they occur in pair. The output table should have one of the rows from the first two rows and remaining rows should be left as is.

The output table would be

| id_1 | id_2 | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-02 | scroll fast | 12 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | scroll fast fast | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | scroll fast fast | 11 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | scroll fast fast | 11 |

I have large dataset, so I cannot filter based on Id_1 and id_2. I am looking for a generic solution.

Test data is here at [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f08e2a6/10).

Comment: Every duplicate occurs as pair, that's what "duplicate" means. Did you mean you want to remove only such duplicates that appear in exactly two rows and none which appear more often?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks for clarifying my question. Yes, thats what I wanted to say.

Comment: Is that year 2020 in ColA a typo and should be 2022 instead? If it's not a typo, how do you determine which row is a "duplicate"? Which DBMS and which version of it do you use? You taged Oracle, but your fiddle is MySQL.

Comment: Your test data is for MySQL and not Oracle.

Comment: @MT0 I am using plsql developer. I am not familiar with fiddle much, therefore, I have edited existing sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and count the size of each group using analytic functions and then delete the second row of a group when there are only 2 rows per group:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2, colA, colB, colC ORDER BY ROWNUM)
           AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2, colA, colB, colC) AS cnt
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid AND src.rn = 2 AND src.cnt = 2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET colC = colC
  DELETE WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table table_name (id_1, id_2, colA, colB, colC) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 'A', 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'A', 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'D', 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'D', 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'D', 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | COLA | COLB | COLC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | A | B | C |
| 1 | 3 | D | E | F |
| 1 | 3 | D | E | F |
| 1 | 3 | D | E | F |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IZzFrgw8)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a combination of `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, both as analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2) cnt,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_1, id_2 ORDER BY id_1) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT id_1, id_2, colA, colB, colC
FROM cte
WHERE cnt <> 2 OR rn = 1;
```

The above logic returns rows appearing only once or appearing 3 times or more.  In the case of pair duplicates, it arbitrarily returns one of them.